# How to change the text colour of a picker .NET maui

Tags: xaml, picker, .net-maui

I am struggling to change the text colour of a picker element in the frontend of my .NET maui project. Here is my code:

```
  <Picker x:Name="picker"
   Title="Project"
   TitleColor="#102D4C"
   TextColor="#102D4C"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"
   ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ProjectName}"
  />
```

[image: white text in picker]

Even after setting the text colour, I am still seeing white text. Any suggestions to change it or is it the default colour because I'm in dark mode?

Comment: I tested and found that the TextColor attribute is set to the text color of the selected element. If you still want to change the text color of the original element in the picker, you may consider using a custom renderer.